# Any way to copy texture coordinates like UVW Map in 3ds max?

Tags: texturing, uv

I'm quite new to blender and I am trying to build a simple room with a repeating texture on all walls. In 3ds Max, this can be done quite simply by applying the UVW Map, setting the required size and copying this modifier to other objects.

[image]

And I spent half a day trying to do the same in Blender.

[image: Wall are a little different size,]

Is there any simple way to do the same in blender? 
I would be grateful for any answers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [tri-planar mapping](http://www.martinpalko.com/triplanar-mapping/), which is even faster to setup and allows to control the scale in one place.

- Create one material for all objects
- Set the projection method of the *Image Texture* node to *Box* (Tri-planar option in Blender)
- Adjust the *Scale* values of the *Mapping* node

[image]

Comment: Indeed faster and simpler! Exactly what I searched for! 
Thank you!